# How to set go back function with ios back navigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I set `deep link` in my app.

So there is a website can open my app with `schema`.

I know user can just click the ios navigator to go back.

But I want to know is any way that I can put my button function in my app's screen just like the ios navigator ?

[image]

Comment: are you using react-navigation library?

Comment: Yes, I use `react-navigation` library

Answer (score 0):

In componentDidMount set

```
 BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPressCheckpointOverview', this.backPressed);
```

here `this.backPressed` is the function which contains your goback functionality.

then in `componentWillUnmount` you remove the event listener

```
 BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPressCheckpointOverview', this.backPressed);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, as far as I know, BackHandler only for Android.